EXCEL -Return list of all values that match more than one criterias office 2019
This function :
=IFERROR(INDEX(Data!$G$2:$G$30000,
 MATCH(1,(Data!$I$2:$I$30000=B8)*
         (Data!$B$2:$B$30000=sum!$C$311)*
         (Data!$AX$2:$AX$30000=0)*
         (Data!$BD$2:$BD$30000<>0),0))," ")

does the work, but returns only the first value in the list.
I tried the Index+ aggregate, but it can relate to only one criteria in one column.

Try: =IFERROR(INDEX(Data!$G$2:$G$30000,AGGREGATE(15,7,(ROW(Data!$G$2:$G$30000)-ROW(Data!$G$2)+1)/((Data!$I$2:$I$30000=B8)*(Data!$B$2:$B$30000=sum!$C$311)*(Data!$AX$2:$AX$30000=0)*(Data!$BD$2:$BD$30000<>0)),ROWS(A$1:A1))),"")
